# C: removing from a full array and only removing first instance of duplicates

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array that I am trying to remove values from, however I run into 2 problems when I try to remove from the array:

1.) When I try to remove from an array that is full, I get a *** Stack Smashing Detected *** error

2.) when my array has multiple duplicates, I only want to remove the first instance, however it seems to remove a random number of instances.

The code I have for the remove function is as follows:

```
int Remove(int* array, int arrayLen, int removeNum)
{
   int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
 {
   if (array[i] == removeNum){
     for(j = i; j < arrayLen; j++){
        array[j] = array[j+1];
      }
      arrayLen--;
   }
}
return arrayLen;
}
```

Where removeNum is user selected in main().

Comment: You must break from the outer loop after you found the first match.

Comment: If the order of the elements in the array doesn't matter, you can speed up the 'removal' process by moving the last element over the one you're removing and then saying the size is shorter.  That involves much less data motion, but may not be appropriate if (as is quite probable) the order matters.

Comment: "removing ... duplicates" misleads.  The function "shrinks" an array when finding a targeted element, if any.  There is no remove "duplicate" attribute to the function itself.  Otherwise good question.

Comment: Gotta say, kind of surprised you didn't get an identifier warning/error when compiling your code conflicting with [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) from the standard library, unless  the module using this thing never includes `stdio.h`, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You're reading past the end of the list because you're inner loop goes too far. (At `j = arrayLen - 1`, `j + 1 = arrayLen`, which is past the end of the array.)
2. You say you only want to remove the first found element, but your code continues past that point. Adding an early `return` (or `break`) fixes that problem.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
int remove(int* array, int arrayLen, int removeNum)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == removeNum) {
            // Stop j at arrayLen - 1, which is the new end of the array
            for(j = i; j < arrayLen - 1; j++) {
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
            }

            // Return the new size
            return arrayLen - 1;
        }
    }

    // If we didn't remove anything, return the original size
    return arrayLen;
}
```

Comment: Adding the return did the fix problem of removing only the first instance, however for some reason, changing j < arrayLen to j < arrayLen - 1 did not fix the stack smashing issue when removing from a full array. any ideas why?

Comment: @MastRofDsastR include the `int main()` test code you're using to build the array passed into your function *as part of your question*.

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be that `arrayLen` is wrong? No way to know without seeing the actual allocation/construction of the array.